# Table with composite primary key for one to many

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have two tables, one is book and the other is order. One book is contained in one order, but one order can contain many books. Therefore it is a one to many relationship.
But instead of recording the Order id in the book table i want to make a separate table(book_order) with a composite primary key(Only book id and order id).

The main reason I'm doing this is because  not all the books will have an order id, only the books that are sold. I just want to know is my design wrong? If so, why is it wrong?

Comment: you are good to go. Always prefer intermediate table to maintain one-many or many-many and many-one  relationship.

Comment: @Piyush so there is nothing wrong with it, I just want to make sure. Because its a one to many relationship and yet i still take the primary keys of both the tables(like in many to many relationships).Furthermore should i show those two attributes(book id and order id) in my er diagram(as a relationship attribute)?

Comment: Are you sure that, one order cannot have more than one same book id?

Comment: @Piyush Yeah that's what i said in the question, that one order can contain many books(book_id) but one book is only found in one order. It's a many to one relationship but i still want to put a new table(like in many to many relationships)

Comment: Because you have one-many relationship, so that's you can achieve also with two table, any specific reason why you want intermediate table?  http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561  and  http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/teach/dbs09/ER-lecture.pdf

Comment: @Piyush thanks for the link, but i already know that for a one to many relationship you put the foreign key on the many side(in this case in book(order_id). But i want to know is there anything wrong with doing it this way, i.e. making a separate table for books and orders(book_Orders ---> bookid, orderid)

Comment: nothing wrong, you just breaking the rules, and working beyond the concept